# How to get the difference between two date and times and show the time running down in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two variables i first variable I am getting the date and time value from date time picker and in second variable i am picking the value of current date and time. Now i want the difference between both of them and show in text like timer running down.

```
<input type="date" id="dates">
    <input type="time"  id="times">
var time=new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB');
        var res = time.slice(0,-3);
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
        var current=today+" "+res; // Here i am getting the value of current date and time

 var datetime=dates.value+" " +times.value; // This value is from date time picker 

 var t=datetime-current;
        alert(t); //here the output is always NaN
```

I want the difference between both date times and show the text like timmer running down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected your code based on assumed values.

```
var dates = {
        value: '2019-09-06'
    };
    var times = {
        value: '10:55:00'
    };

    var time=new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB');
    var res = time.slice(0,-3);
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    var current=today+" "+res; // Here i am getting the value of current date and time

    var datetime=dates.value+" " +times.value; // This value is from date time picker

    var t= ( new Date( datetime ) ).getTime() - ( new Date( current ) ).getTime();
    alert(t);
```